# multi button tag multi ple view

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

On click each button showing subview view contains learn and play option.While clicking , want to show the different view depends on the uibutton selection.Here my code .

```
-(IBAction)animals
{

CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.animalsbut];

pv = [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:animalsbut withContentView:alertvu    delegate:self];
pv.tag=1;

}
-(IBAction)birds
{
   CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.birdsbut];

pv = [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:birdsbut withContentView:alertvu delegate:self];
pv.tag=2;
//[self checkingme:pv.tag];
}
-(IBAction)direct
 {  
  CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.direcbut];
pv = [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:direcbut withContentView:alertvu delegate:self];
pv.tag=4;
}
-(IBAction)fruit
{

CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.fruitbut];
pv = [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:fruitbut withContentView:alertvu delegate:self];
pv.tag=3;
}
```

method

```
-(IBAction)check:(NSInteger)sender
{
UIButton *mybutton =(UIButton*) [self.view viewWithTag:sender];

if(pv.tag==1)
{
    NSLog(@"button log%d",mybutton.tag);
if(mybutton.tag==0)
{

    animallearn *aview=[[animallearn alloc]initWithNibName:@"animallearn" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aview animated:YES];
    [pv performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
}
else //(mybutton.tag==1)
{
    playview *pview=[[playview alloc]initWithNibName:@"playview" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pview animated:YES];
   [pv performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
}

}
else if(pv.tag==2)
{
    if(mybutton.tag==0)
    {
        birdview *aview=[[birdview alloc]initWithNibName:@"birdview" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aview animated:YES];
        [pv performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];

    }
   else if(mybutton.tag==1)
   {
       playview *pview=[[playview alloc]initWithNibName:@"playview" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:pview animated:YES];
       [pv performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
   }
}
else if(pv.tag==3)
{
    if(mybutton.tag==0)
    {
        fruitview *aview=[[fruitview alloc]initWithNibName:@"fruitview" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aview animated:YES];
        [pv performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];           
    }
    else if(mybutton.tag==1)
    {
        playview *pview=[[playview alloc]initWithNibName:@"playview" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pview animated:YES];
        [pv performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
    }
}
else if(pv.tag==4)
{
    if(mybutton.tag==0)
    {
        directview *aview=[[directview alloc]initWithNibName:@"directview" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aview animated:YES];
         [pv performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
    }
    else if(mybutton.tag==1)
    {
        playview *pview=[[playview alloc]initWithNibName:@"playview" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pview animated:YES];
        [pv performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
    }
}
else
{

    return ;
 }
 }
```

Here problem is whenever i second button it showing the button tag 0 view only in all the cases?Can any one help me to sort it out

Comment: why do you pass NSInteger as a sender? It must be the button itself, not its tag

Comment: is the NSLog printing correct tag value?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli it always showing 0 only

Comment: post the code where you are initializing the button and how you are setting tag value.And also once modify your code as suggested and check it is working

Comment: @Fazil it is always showing 0 because you are interpreting the sender as NSInteger whereas it should be of id type, which makes your myButton nil and calling myButton.tag returns 0, see answer below for correction! this should solve your problem!

Comment: its UIview for showing two buttons in IB @PratyushaTerli

Comment: Then in IB set the button tag value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also set the tags of UIButtons/UIViews you want to access via tag. like secondButton.tag = 3; and the sender argument passed is not of type NSInteger it is of UIView, so change it like this! This is should solve your problem!

```
-(IBAction)check:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *mybutton =(UIButton*) sender;
    // continue whatever you were doing earlier!
}
```